# What is the best approach for handling modules that don't have a type definition file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm using a module called `three-orbit-controls` in my typescript/react project. This module does not have a @types package so as I understand I will need to write a type definition file. I'm confused as to the best way to approach this. Ideally I would like to have a file called `index.d.ts` that defines this module that I can add to as I use more features of the library. I have added this file to my project however the typescript compiler claims that it can't find the module. Here is my `index.d.ts` file that is in the root of my project

```
declare module 'three-orbit-controls' {
    export default class OrbitControls {}
}
```

I'm trying to include this module in the following way

```
import OrbitControls from 'three-oribit-controls';
```

However when I do this the typescript compiler claims it can't find the module. Is there something basic I'm missing? I even tried to include the type def file in my code by adding

```
/// <reference path="../index.d.ts" />
```

However this does not work and it would seem strage that I would have this line to each file that I require `three-orbit-controls`. Why does typescript think the module is not defined? What is the best way to define a module in a .d.ts file? Is there a way to have a .d.ts file that my entire project can see with out importing a .d.ts file everywhere?

Comment: Are you including the index.d.ts file in the set of files you are passing to tsc?

Comment: I have tried adding `/// <reference path="../index.d.ts" />` to the top of the file. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Rather than do that, just pass in the file to the `tsc` command: `tsc main.ts index.d.ts` (or use `{"include": ["main.ts", "index.d.ts"]}` in your `tsconfig.json`